# RegEx: search all css-classes in string (with(/out) spacing)

Tags: javascript, regex

Recently I have come across with a tricky searching condition I can't really puzzle out.
The goal is to search within css-classes and do some replacements, not a big deal.

In short, I need to locate in a text block all css-classes in a string that starts with a dot AND to include this dot into the capturing group. The problem is that there can be multiple classes on one string, and some of them could be separated with space, some not.

Here are examples of such strings:

```
Need to match:

.class
.class-media.other-class__item:nth-child(n)
.class-media .class-media__title::before

Don't need to match:

sometext.url.domain
```

I can easily make a regexp that can fulfill my task without capturing a dot before class name, but with it task becomes tricky.

So far I create this one:

```
(^|\s)(\.)([a-zA-Z_-]{1}[\w-_]+)/g
```

but it doesn't allow to capture classes without spacing and not capture ".url.domain"

Here is an example on https://regex101.com/r/MWLjLa/1/

Note about XY problem: this searching run in JS, so maybe there's a way to solve in not in just one regexp.

Comment: This is within a CSS-File right?

Comment: Well, not actually -- within a variable that consists generated css-styles.

Comment: @Alex.Default Do you mean like this? `\w+(?:\.\w+)+|(\.\w+(?:-\w+)*)` using a capturing group? https://regex101.com/r/BGAWGQ/1

Comment: @The fourth bird, something close, but I need to capture only in strings that start with a dot =) "Don't match" actually means "exclude from results/ don't capture", sorry if it was unclear

Comment: Those strings that start with a dot are in group 1 (highlighted in green on regex101) You can get those values with Javascript.

Comment: "sometext.url.domain" is also captured, but I need to exclude it from results

Comment: @Alex.Default See for example https://ideone.com/kl0ms0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example data, you might use a capturing group. You could first match what you don't want and capture in a group what you want to keep.

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)+|(\.\w+(?:-\w+)*)
```

In parts

- `\w+(?:\.\w+)+` To prevent capturing, first match word chars repeated 1+ times by `.` and word chars
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\.\w+` Match the starting dot, 1+ word chars
  - `(?:-\w+)*` Repeat matching -` and 1+ word chars
- `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gdOtXD/1)

```js
const regex = /\w+(?:\.\w+)+|(\.\w+(?:-\w+)*)/g;
const str = `Match:

.class
.class-media.other-class__item:nth-child(n)
.class-media .class-media__title::before

Don't match:

sometext.url.domain
sometext.url.domain.test.test`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (undefined !== m[1]) console.log(m[1]);
}
```

If you want to use the match in the replacement:

```js
const regex = /(\w+(?:\.\w+)+)|(\.\w+(?:-\w+)*)/g;
const str = `Match:

.class
.class-media.other-class__item:nth-child(n)
.class-media .class-media__title::before

Don't match:

sometext.url.domain
sometext.url.domain.test.test`;
let m;

let result = str.replace(regex, (_, g1, g2) => undefined !== g2 ? g2 + "mewmewmew" : g1);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hmmm, it helps me to get these values, but my goal, as I stated, is to somehow modify them in the original text, something like `cssText.replace(/\w+(?:\.\w+)+|(\.\w+(?:-\w+)*)/g, '$1mewmewmew')`. But with this regexp undesired results also managed to get treated as the first capturing group ($1)

Comment: @Alex.Default I have added another example if you want to use the value with a replacement.

Comment: I don't really get right now this "match undesirable and capture" magic, but I will look into it. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: These pages might be helpful https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html and https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your problem right:

So how about this: `^(\.[\w-]+\s?)+/gm`

See the example here: https://regex101.com/r/SslScl/1

---

It has to start with a dot `^\.` , then comes the class name `[\w-]+`.

Since there can be more classes in one line we add `+` after brackets -> 
`^(\.[\w-]+)+` so it will find .class1-xxx.class2-yyy.

But there can (but don't need to) be a white space between so we add `\s?`. Add also multi-line search and you are done:

`^(\.[\w-]+\s?)+/gm`

---

You can change it so it will find multiple space-characters between two classes.

Comment: Sadly, multiple capturing results into single capturing ".class .class-media.other-class__item", while there should be three different results ".class", ".class-media" and ".other-class__item".